# Create partial dependence plot using H2O in spark?

Tags: h2o, sparkling-water

I am trying to create partial dependent plot using the following code

```
rf_pdp = rf_model .partial_plot(data = htest, cols = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3'], plot=True)
rf_pdp
```

it runs without error and generate a table with mean_response, stddev_response, std_error_mean_response for each variables. BUT there is no plot. Is that because I run the code in Spark environment?

I am running H2O cluster version: 3.20.0.7 using Sparkling Water under Qubole

```
%pyspark
# start h2o
from pysparkling import *
import h2o
hc = H2OContext.getOrCreate(spark)

# clean up the cluster just in case
h2o.remove_all()

# import data
iris = h2o.import_file("http://h2o-public-test-data.s3.amazonaws.com/smalldata/iris/iris_wheader.csv")

# convert response column to a factor
iris['class'] = iris['class'].asfactor()

# set the predictor names
predictors = iris.columns[:-1]

# split into train and validation sets
train, valid = iris.split_frame(ratios = [.8], seed = 1234)

# random forest
from h2o.estimators.random_forest import H2ORandomForestEstimator

rf_model = H2ORandomForestEstimator(
                score_each_iteration=True,
                score_tree_interval = 5,
                max_runtime_secs = 1800,
                stopping_metric = 'logloss', 
                stopping_tolerance=0.001,
                stopping_rounds= 3,
                sample_rate = 0.7, 
                col_sample_rate_per_tree = 0.7,                
                ntrees=1000,
                balance_classes=False,
                seed=456,
                nfolds=5
                )

rf_model.train(x=predictors, y ='class', training_frame=train)

# plot
rf_model.plot()
```

Comment: please provide details on your environment (what version of H2O-3, matplotlib, Sparkling-Water, and Spark are you using) and please also provide a fully reproducible code snippet so I can try to reproduce your issue (you can use the iris dataset for example this link includes an s3 link to that dataset though it is using kmeans so you will have to change that http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/estimate_k.html?highlight=iris. )

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I just added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for plotting

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import io

matplotlib.use('agg')

def show(p):
    img = io.StringIO()
    p.savefig(img, format='svg')
    img.seek(0)
    print("%html <div>" + img.getvalue() + "</div>")

plt.clf()
rf_model.partial_plot(data = htest, cols = plot_varimp_df["variable"].tolist(), nbins=2, plot=True)
show(plt)
```